# Visualization Bug When dismissing the keyboard in splitviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

i have a split view controller with a search box on the left controller. I simply call:

```
[self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

every time i want the keyboard to be dismissed (cell clicked, scroll bar scrolled and so on.)
When the keyboard is dismissed, the temporary effect is the one you see in the pictures, and then then the scroll bar resizes itself to the right dimensions.
Do you have an idea of the reasons of this behavior and tips on how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you listening for the keyboard hide / show events and running code  for their callbacks. If so post this code too

Comment: no i'm not listening to keyboard events

Comment: @matteosilv I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?